# difficulty with enabling/disabling JComponents with a checkbox in Java

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, actionlistener, jcomponent

i am having little difficulty here with disabling/enabling few JComponents with a checkbox in run-time. I have tried to do `if(checkbox.isSelected(){}`  but it didn't worked. When i try to add `addActionListener(this)` i get an error "method addActionListiner in class AbstractButton cannot be applied to given types : required Action listiner: found JudgeMain (its a class name) - leaking "this" in constructor

```
public class JudgeMain extends JFrame {
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
LogInJ id = new LogInJ();
public String IdNumber;
public JudgeMain(LogInJ id) 
{
    initComponents();
    ButtonGroup();
    this.id = id;
    initDetails();
    yesCB.addActionListener(this);
    if(yesCB.isSelected())
    {
        timeF.setEnabled(true);
        catF.setEnabled(true);
        yearsCB.setEnabled(true);
        monthsCB.setEnabled(true);            
    }
}
```

help appreciated thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `JudgeMain` does not represent the type `ActionListener`.

You would need to implement this interface to make it possible to call

```
yesCB.addActionListener(this);
```

or just use an anonymous listener (Note, no need to check the source):

```
yesCB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      timeF.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
      catF.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
      yearsCB.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
      monthsCB.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
}});
```

---

*Side Note:* The preferred approach is to create an instance of `JFrame` and use directly rather than subclassing the class.

Comment: True in my case it is better to use anonymous listener, thank you :) your solution works for me best :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to implement `ActionListener`:

Something like this should work (although I can't be sure since your original code did not compile):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JudgeMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    LogInJ id = new LogInJ();
    public String IdNumber;

    public JudgeMain(LogInJ id) {
        initComponents();
        ButtonGroup();
        this.id = id;
        initDetails();
        yesCB.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (yesCB == e.getSource()) {
            timeF.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
            catF.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
            yearsCB.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
            monthsCB.setEnabled(yesCB.isSelected());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ChangeListener on a JCheckBox instead of an ActionListener if you want.